# Docker login error "Not enough memory resources are available"

Tags: docker, aws-ecr

I'm using Windows 10 and Docker Desktop Engine 19.03.5.

I'm trying to create an AWS ECR repository and push an image.

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email  # successful
docker login -u AWS -p eyJwYXlsb2F... # failed
```

Error:

> Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out:`Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.`

Enough memory and disk space.

Comment: When you say the memory is enough it is related to the Docker VM?

Comment: Not so sure.  "Not enough memory resources are available to process this command." is part of the whole error message.  my machine has 64 GB memory. and Docker Desktop memory is currently 4096 MB.

Comment: As first you can try to increase the memory assigned to the Docker VM to understand if the issue is related directly to this or not

Comment: yeah .. I already played with the Docker Desktop memory. None worked.

Answer (score 21):

On Windows 10:
it's related to the Windows Credential Manager getting filled up over time with "git" entries - run this command and the issue fixed.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %i in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr git ^| findstr Target') do cmdkey /delete %j
```

Comment: Running this command in Powershell returns an error, but it works fine in a normal command prompt.  This did resolve the problem for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It worked for me, but it will delete all your git entries.

Comment: you are the man!!

Comment: Worked for me, I just had to swap `git` for `vscode` as I had a lot of those: `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %i in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr vscode ^| findstr Target') do cmdkey /delete %j`

Answer (score 3):

As someone else also mentioned it's because Windows Credential Manager is getting filled up.

Fix On windows 11 (similar in Windows 10:

Navigate to Control Panel => Manage Windows Credentials => Select Windows Credentials tab

(or search for "Windows Credential Manager" in the Start menu.)

Create a backup by clicking "Backup Credentials" (optional) and Remove the credentials you don't need.

For me the "Adobe" app had created too many credentials and after deleting some I was able to login to ECR docker successfully.